# Duplicate column name after altering a field

Tags: mysql, django, django-migrations

I added a textfield "field2" to a model and later modified it to a ForeignKey. After which when I try to run migrations, i get duplicate column name for field2. How can this be resolved. Also, i have one more field which is a foreignkey.

Here is my table:

```
class dummy(models.Model):
    field1 = models.ForeignKey(Table1)
    field2 = models.ForeignKey(Table2)
```

field2 was a textfield earlier. Then I modified it to point to another table, making it a foreignkey and then when I run migrations, the duplicate column error appears. How can this be resolved?

DB being used is mySQL

makemigrations and sqlmigrate works fine. migrate is showing up error:

```
./manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages
  Apply all migrations: <LIST OF TABLES>
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying assessment.0002_auto_20160302_1904...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 222, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 148, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/schema.py", line 43, in add_field
    super(DatabaseSchemaEditor, self).add_field(model, field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 398, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 111, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'field2'")
```

Comment: First delete the field and run migrations. Then re-add it as a ForeignKey and re-run migrations.

Comment: Manually delete the field in DB you mean?

Comment: No, from your model..

Comment: Please provide the exact output of the command that fail. And btw, is it `makemigrations` or `migrate` that fails? If `migrate` fails, please provide the migration generated by `makemigrations`.

Comment: @Selcuk - I commented out Field2 and run migrations, it is giving the same error again! "Duplicate column name 'field2'". makemigrations and sqlmigrate are going smooth. It is migrate that is showing up error

Comment: You might have a migration file remaining from your previous attempts. Delete the offending .py file first.

Comment: @Selcuk Deleted the .py migration file. That's not helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```